# How to get indexpaths of cells in UICollectionView for specific content offset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview

I want to know indexPaths of cells in UICollectionView that will be if I scroll to a specific content offset. For example if contentOffset is {0,0} - we will see [0,1,2,3] indexes. And if contentOffset is {0,100} we will see [2,3,4,5] indexes. What is the simple way to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to get that info while the cells are visible? If so, UICollectionView has a method `indexPathsForVisibleItems()` that returns an array of `NSIndexPath`. If not, you can probably calculate it yourself. Should be easy if all cells are the same size.

Comment: It would good if you could explain why you want to do this. It sounds like you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Sounds like you are don't understand what I want. I'll give you some details. So when I'm on offset {0,0} I want to know which of indexes I will see if I scroll to offset {0,100}? indexPathsForVisibleItems() is not what I'm want. This method will sound like indexPathsForContentOffset()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The key method was in collectionViewLayout propery. So if you want to find which of indexPaths will be visible if you scroll to a specific content offset you need to call:

```
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:CGRectMake(0, target.y, scrollView.width, scrollView.height)];
```

You will find array of **UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes** class who told you an indexPath